# Excel Interop RPC server Unavailable while creating PivotTables

Tags: vb.net, excel, ssis, excel-interop

Short intro.  I have a largish excel file with an embedded PivotCache that I need to create a new pivot table in.  Long story on creating the pivot table, suffice it to say, it's the ONLY way I can get at the underlying data.  I'm using SSIS with a VB.net script task in order to open the file, create the pivot table, then save it out.  (I read the file back in later with a standard excel connection object.)

My problem, is it is incredibly unstable.  It fails probably 75% of the time it runs...Sometimes it runs fine the next time I run it, it fails miserably.  I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong, or if what I'm doing is the "wrong" way to go about it.  My code is below.  I've googled around and just can't seem to find anything that helps.  Is the excel interop assembly just unstable?

It will run !00% of the time with the pivot table add statements commented out.  so I know at least that section is not quite right.

```
    Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application

    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Dts.Variables("ImportFileName").Value.ToString)


    Dim ptCache As Excel.PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches(1)
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    For Each displayWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet In wb.Worksheets
        If displayWorksheet.Name = "pTable" Then
            displayWorksheet.Delete()
        End If
    Next displayWorksheet

    xlApp.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual

    Try
        xlSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add()
        xlSheet.Name = "pTable"

        Dim oPT = ptCache.CreatePivotTable(xlSheet.Range("A1"), "NewPivot", True)

        oPT.AddDataField(oPT.PivotFields("UPC").name)
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "UPC")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "Color")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "Size")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "Style")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "Department")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "SubDepartment")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "Class")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "SubClass")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "VendorNumber")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "VendorDescription")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "SKUType")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "SKUStatus")
        AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(oPT, "FirstReceiptDate")

        oPT.RowGrand = False
        oPT.ColumnGrand = False

        xlApp.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic

        wb.Save()
        wb.Close()

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    Catch ex As Exception

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure

    Finally

        xlApp.Application.Quit()

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)

    End Try



End Sub

Sub AddPivotFieldsAndRemoveSubTotal(ByRef xlPivotTable As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable, ByVal PivotFieldName As String)
    xlPivotTable.AddFields(xlPivotTable.PivotFields(PivotFieldName).name, , , True)
    CType(xlPivotTable.PivotFields(PivotFieldName), Excel.PivotField).Subtotals(1) = False
End Sub
```

Comment: So what kind of exceptions are you catching when you run it? I won't speak to a general experience, but for me the Excel Interop is very stable but also very unforgiving.

Comment: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8.  Searching around, it's basically "Object Required."  Personally I think I have some sort of memory leak, or I'm blowing out the available memory somehow.

Comment: It seems that the below may also be true for SSIS: "It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)"

Comment: "suffice it to say, it's the ONLY way I can get at the underlying data". Are you absolutely sure - this is quite strange given that you first need to point the pivot table at some kind of internal or external data.

Comment: I only wish @ElectricLlama  The workbook is provided to us from a 3rd part vendor.  The data is actually disconnected from the original datasource.  It's actually kind of a cool feature of excel in that you can store the data with the spreadsheet as a PivotCache.  I had looked around quite a bit prior to this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748584/ms-excel-pivot-table-accessing-the-source-data-when-it-isnt-a-tab-in-the-sp

Comment: I see. Perhaps it would be more reliable to build a standalone app (in Powershell or console app) and call that from a step in SSIS. So SSIS calls a step out of process and the result should be an Excel file that you can reference from SSIS

Comment: I have a feeling that's what I'm going to do.  I'll update once I figure it out.